# How do I call my AWS Lambda function from a local python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating a CRUD application using python. I have created my dynamoDB database on AWS and I would like read and write to it from my program. I have created an AWS Lambda function that is being stored in the cloud under my AWS account. How can i call my function from within my local python program? The tutorials i have seen seem to target local dynamoDB applications

Answer (score 2):

You need two things:

1. IAM role or IAM user  with **permissions** to call your lambda function in your code.
2. To actually perform the calling action, using [invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) method in boto3.

An alternative is to call your lambda function through an **API Gateway**. This does not require IAM roles or IAM user credentials for the caller. How to use lambda with API Gateway is shown in the following link:

- [Build an API Gateway REST API with Lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do in your Python script is call the [invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) function.